# Cannot auto-complete for map iterator in cross-referenced class templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, iterator, clion, auto

I am writing some C++ code where I have a few class templates that cross reference each other (if I understand these words correctly).  One of the class contains a map container, and I cannot get auto-completion to work for the map iterator when I use it in a member function of another class, either in JetBrain CLion or VS Code.

Below is a minimal working example, the code compiles and runs fine. I use the pattern `*****` to highlight some for loops and whether the auto-completion works or not. As you can see, the position of the class declaration also matters. I guess template deduction is hard?

I would sincerely appreciate it a lot if someone can explain the reasons behind them and what I should do to make auto-completion work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <int D> class Planet;
template <int D> class PlanetList;
template <int D> class BHtree;
template <class T, int D> class DataSet;

/* In addition, if I move the declaration of BHtree before other classes, both cannot auto-complete
 ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
    ...
    for (auto &it : ds.planet_list.planets) {
        std::cout << it.second.mass; // <== still cannot auto-complete after typing it or it.second
    }
    ...
    for (auto it = ds.planet_list.planets.begin(); it != ds.planet_list.planets.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << it->second.mass; // <== cannot auto-complete after typing it or it->second
    }
    ...
 ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
 */

template <int D> class Planet {
public:
    double mass {0};
    double pos[D];
};

template <int D> class PlanetList {
public:
    uint32_t num_planets{0};
    std::map<uint32_t, Planet<D>> planets;
};

template <class T, int D> class DataSet {
public:
    BHtree<D> tree;
    PlanetList<D> planet_list;
};


template <int D>
class BHtree {
public:
    struct TreeNode {
        double pos[D];
    };
    TreeNode *tree;

    template <class T, class F>
    void FindPlanet(DataSet<T, D> &ds, F DensityKernel, int loop_count) {
        //***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
        for (auto &it : ds.planet_list.planets) {
            std::cout << it.second.mass; // <== Cannot auto-complete after typing it or it.second
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (auto it = ds.planet_list.planets.begin(); it != ds.planet_list.planets.end(); it++) {
            std::cout << it->second.mass; // <== This, however, can auto-complete for it and it->second
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        //***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
    }
};

constexpr int dim {3};

int main()
{
    DataSet<float, dim> ds;
    ds.tree.tree = new BHtree<dim>::TreeNode[2];

    ds.planet_list.planets.emplace(0, Planet<dim>());
    ds.planet_list.planets.emplace(1, Planet<dim>());

    //***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
    for (auto &it : ds.planet_list.planets) {
        std::cout << it.second.mass << std::endl; // <== auto-complete without issue for it and for it.second
    }
    //***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
    ds.tree.FindPlanet(ds, nullptr, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why add `FindPlanet` to `BHtree` when it clearly searches for something in a `DataSet`

Comment: which C++ compiler do you use? I tried with g++ and Visual-C++ and only get suggestions when the type of the iterator is fully known (only in `main`). Inside the function `FindPlanet` the type of the iterator is not know (`<unnamed>` and `auto`) for the language server, tooltips differ depending on the C++ configuration

Comment: what is the use `num_planets`, `map` knows its size

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for your comments! You made a few great points!
(1) I thought putting definitions on top of the file should help. But it didn't. Also, I tried to put `FindPlanet` in `DataSet`, `it` in `for (auto &it : planet_list.planets)` still does not have auto-completion. `it` in the other loop has auto-completion in CLion but not VS Code.
(2) I used g++. I think I understand that the type of the iterator is not known with `auto`. But why it is still not known even if I specify `planet_list.planets.begin()`? That puzzles me.
(3) I guess `num_planets` is redundant, haha.

Comment: `auto` means: let the compiler determine the type of the variable, the compiler can but the compiler only have to do it on full known template type arguments, the intellisense has to do it with incomplete type arguments inside the template, I don't know what the compiler tells the Language Server, maybe I don't use the latest g++